# Naive Solver of Matrix with Periodic Boundary Conditions Feedback

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, matrix

I am creating an \$O(n)\$ solver for an \$Ax = b\$ system where \$A\$ has the form
\$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
a_1 &  b_1   &&&d_{u}\\ c_1 &  a_2   & b_2\\& \ddots & \ddots & \ddots\\&   &  c_{n-2}&a_{n-1}& b_{n-1}\\ d_{l} &&&c_{n-1}& a_{n}
\end{pmatrix}         
\$

To do this, I wrote a basic function that just performs Gaussian elimination. I was wondering if there are any immediate ways to improve the code below. My main goal is obviously speed, so I would like to know of any tricks that would minimize memory usage (while preserving \$A\$) and the number of computations being performed. I have already made \$A\$ into a sparse matrix which helped a fair bit already. Also to note, that even though the code is in python, it's not written in a pythonic way because I typically develop initial code (for easier debugging) in python before writing the final version in C.

```
def solve_periodic_sparseA_vectB(A, b, results, corner_upper, corner_lower):
    n = b.shape[0]
    results[0] = b[0]
    results[n - 1] = b[n - 1]
    supra_diag = A[2].copy()
    last_col = np.zeros(n - 1)  # excludes final val main
    last_col[0] = corner_upper
    last_col[n - 2] = supra_diag[n - 2]
    last_row_val = corner_lower
    current_main = A[1][0]
    next_main = A[1][1]
    last_main = A[1][n - 1]

    for i in range(n - 2):
        # divide by pivot
        ci = current_main
        results[i] = results[i] / ci
        supra_diag[i] = A[2][i + 1] / ci
        last_col[i] /= ci
        # -aRi + Ri+1 --> Ri+1
        a = A[0][i]
        results[i + 1] = b[i + 1] - a * results[i]
        next_main -= a * supra_diag[i]
        last_col[i + 1] -= a * last_col[i]
        # -aRi + Rn --> Rn
        a = last_row_val
        results[n - 1] = results[n - 1] - a * results[i]
        last_main -= a * last_col[i]
        last_row_val = (A[0][i + 1] if i == n - 3 else 0.0) - a * supra_diag[i]

        current_main = next_main
        next_main = A[1][i + 2]

    i = n - 2
    # divide by pivot
    ci = current_main
    last_col[i] /= ci
    results[i] /= ci
    a = last_row_val
    results[n - 1] -= a * results[i]
    last_main -= a * last_col[i]
    # solve last
    results[n - 1] /= last_main
    # last column
    for i in range(n - 1):
        results[i] -= last_col[i] * results[n - 1]
    # supra-diagonal (final pass)
    for i in range(n - 2, 0, -1):
        results[i - 1] -= supra_diag[i - 1] * results[i]
```

EDIT:
Example usage would be something like

```
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sig = 1.0
    n = 5
    # sparse matrix where rows 0 1 2 are the sub main and supra diagonals respectively
    A = np.r_['0,2', np.full(n, -sig), np.full(n, 1 + 2 * sig), np.full(n, -sig)]
    b = np.arange(n, dtype=np.float64)
    x = np.empty_like(b)
    solve_periodic_sparseA_vectB(A, b, x, -sig, -sig)
```

Comment: Can you include your imports, as well as a small example matrix to run equivalence tests?